# Eine Alternative für "Was nutzt es"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Was nutzt es, man sich eine Fender kauft u sie nicht spielt. Das Geld, das man für eine Gitarre ausgegeben hat, ist vor die Hunde gegangen.

Gibt es eine Alternative für "Was nutzt es?"

Comment: Oh, I was just confused how you could be playing a [Fender](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_(Schifffahrt)). I guess that a [Fender](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_(Musikinstrumente)) can be played, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is even one more thing I would like to talk about here.

First of all, alternatives:

```
Es hat keinen Nutzen, wenn man sich eine Fender kauft und sie nicht spielt.

Es bringt nichts, wenn man sich eine Fender kauft und sie nicht spielt. (more colloquial)

Es hat keinen Sinn, wenn man sich eine Fender kauft und sie nicht spielt. (-> does not make any sense)
```

Hope that helps.

Still there is a second thing I would like to mention here.

You would barely say (I think you would not say that at all)

```
 Das Geld ist vor die Hunde gegangen.
```

Someone who goes "vor die Hunde" is someone that is basically a complete mess. He has probably lost his work and wife and children for example and has now a **very** messed up living situation.

You would not use this prase with money.

You would rather say the following:

```
Das Geld hat er verschwendet.

Das Geld ist komplett verschwendet.

Das Geld, das er dafür ausgegeben hat, ist komplette Verschwendung.
```

Or another one, which is a more colloquial way:

```
Das Geld, das er dafür ausgegeben hat, hat er aus dem Fenster geworfen.
```

Which means that he has basically thrown the money out of the windows and refers to using money in a way that does not make any sense.